# Get image position (windows store apps, xaml , c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing an app for windows phone and i need to get the location/position of the image that the user moves.

```
var Pic= (CompositeTransform)MovingImage.RenderTransform;
            Pic.TranslateX += (e.Delta.Translation.X/2);
            Pic.TranslateY += (e.Delta.Translation.Y/2);
```

that's the code im using to move the picture and i need to check when it "touches" another picture , for that , i need to check the position of the picture, can someone help me with that ? 
thanks to the helpers

Comment: Is the element panel a Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the the `Canvas.GetLeft` `Canvas.GetTop` `Canvas.GetBottom` and `Canvas.GetRight` assuming that you are using the Image inside a Canvas.

Check the MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)